# PHP titles modification

Tags: php

I'm developing a script that for [scholar.google.com](http://scholar.google.com).  The script needs to modify article titles obtained from http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed.

So the script has to remove all special characters, numbers and non-latin letters from the title as well as the word/sign that those just mentioned "touch" (words that are not separated from special signs, letters or non-latin letters with a space).

So I need it to transform for example this:

> Large conductance Ca2+ -activated K+ channel activation with NS1619
>   decreases myogenic and neurogenic contractions of rat detrusor smooth
>   muscle.

into:

> Large conductance channel activation with decreases myogenic and
>   neurogenic contractions of rat detrusor smooth muscle.

Another example is to convert this:

> LTP impairment by fractalkine/CX3CL1 in mouse hippocampus is mediated
>   through the activity of adenosine receptor type 3 (A3R)

into:

> LTP impairment by in mouse hippocampus is mediated through the
>   activity of adenosine receptor type

What I already have is:

```
function rename_article ($article){
 global $alphabet;
 $pos_hyphen = strpos($article, "-");
 if ($pos_hyphen===FALSE){
   $article = preg_replace ("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/"," ",$article);
  for ($i = 0; $article[$i]; $i++)
  {
   $article .= !is_numeric($article[$i]) ? $article[$i] : "";
  }
  return $article;
 }
 $substr = substr($article, 0, $pos_hyphen);

 $pos1 = strrpos($substr, ' ');
 if ($pos1 === FALSE){
  $pos1 =0;
 }
 $substr2 = substr($article, $pos_hyphen, strlen($article));
 $pos2 = strpos($substr2, ' ');

 if ($pos2 === FALSE){
  $pos2 = strlen($substr2);
 }

 $length1 = $pos_hyphen-$pos1;
 $length2 = $length1+$pos2;

 $substr = substr($article,$pos1,$length2);
 if ($length1<4){
  $article = str_ireplace ($substr, '' ,$article);
  rename_article ($article);
 }
 else{
  foreach ($alphabet as $letter){
   if (strpos($substr, $letter) != FALSE){
    $article = str_ireplace ($substr, '' ,$article);
    rename_article ($article);
   }
   else{
    $article = preg_replace ("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/"," ",$article);
    for ($i = 0; $article[$i]; $i++)
    {
     $article .= !is_numeric($article[$i]) ? $article[$i] : "";
    }
    return $article;
   }
  }
 }
 $article = preg_replace ("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/"," ",$article);
 for ($i = 0; $article[$i]; $i++)
 {
  $article .= !is_numeric($article[$i]) ? $article[$i] : "";
 }
 return $article;
};
```

But it does not exclude the words as I have described above.

HELP PLEASE

Comment: What about naturally double-barreled names? There obviously must be titles like "blah blah Tay-Sachs blah blah", where your rule would strip "Tay-Sachs".

Comment: these occur very seldom and we don't need them. or other words we have to exclude them as well to make it work for the most of the search results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I would have gone about this a little differently than you did above. I would have first broken the title down into words then kept only the acceptable words.

```
function rename_article( $title ) {
    $title = rtrim( $title, ".?!" );  // Added for punctuation at end of title
    $titleWords = explode( ' ', $title );
    $newTitle = '';
    foreach( $titleWords as $titleWord ) {
        if( !preg_match( '/[^a-zA-Z]/', $titleWord ) ) {
            if( empty( $newTitle ) )
                $newTitle = $titleWord;
            else
                $newTitle .= ' ' . $titleWord;
        }
    }
    return $newTitle;
}
```

Comment: Anything with non-letters anywhere will get rejected (i.e., the pattern is non-a-z-or-A-Z and I choose strings that don't have the non-letters by the !preg_match()).

Comment: Thanks!

but won't this result in:
Large conductance  K  channel activation with decreases myogenic and neurogenic contractions of rat detrusor smooth muscle

so the "K" will still be there

Comment: I don't think so because it is 'K+' so the '+' will eliminate it. If just a 'K' is in the title it will be accepted as a legal word, just like 'A' would in something like "A Large Conductance".

Comment: Do you have any idea how to make the dot from the end of the article name an exception NOT to eliminate words?

Comment: @ovsky: just add a dot at the end inside the square brackets (or see my answer).

Comment: Be careful on adding the dot within the square brackets for all comparisons because it will now accept a word like **conductance.value**. If it is just want to allow punctuation at the end you might put in an `rtrim()` before the `explode()` [I edited my answer to show this].

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple approach for the given examples:

```
function rename_article($article) {
    $return = "";
    $array = explode(" ",$article);
    foreach($array as $word) {
        if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z.]*$/",$word)) {
            $return.= " ".$word;
        }
    }
    return trim($return);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split title by whitespace first, then check "word" by "word" whether it is valid or should be removed?

```
$title = "LTP impairment by fractalkine/CX3CL1 in mouse hippocampus is 
   mediated through the activity of adenosine receptor     type 3 (A3R)";

$title_words = preg_split('/\s+/', $title);

$new_title = "";

foreach ($title_words as $word) {
  if (preg_match('/^[a-z]+$/i', $word)) {
     $new_title .= " $word";
  } 
}

$new_title =  trim($new_title);

echo $new_title;
```

result

```
LTP impairment by in mouse hippocampus is mediated through 
the activity of adenosine receptor type
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is define the actual pattern of words we're removing and put it into an array.

Obviously + and - are there, and I guess / as well, and anything with a number? and ()'s too. Hopefully I'm not missing anything. The fact that the numeric characters guarantee disqualification means that if you want to, you don't even have to use an ounce of RegEx, you can just stick them into the array by hand even.

Then, take the original sentence and explode it on space ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php )

Then, take a nice little walk and compare the value to your original array ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php )

If the value of your exploded array doesn't contain any of the patterns you've already used, toss it into a new array.

Put the Array back together ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php )

trim() and stick a period on the end if you want.

Rather than using all that RegEX, i'd personally just strpos() http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$string = "Large conductance Ca2+ -activated K+ channel activation
with NS1619 decreases myogenic and neurogenic contractions of rat detrusor smooth muscle.";

$string2 = "LTP impairment by fractalkine/CX3CL1 in mouse hippocampus is
 mediated through the activity of adenosine receptor type 3 (A3R)";


function getTitle($string){
    $s = explode(' ', $string);
    foreach($s as $key => $value){
        if(preg_match('/([a-z]+[0-9\+]|[\-]+[a-z0-9\+])|[0-9]/i', $value)){
           unset($s[$key]);
        }
    }
    return implode(' ', $s);
}

 echo getTitle($string2);
 echo getTitle($string);
```

output

```
LTP impairment by in mouse hippocampus is mediated through the activity of adenosine receptor type
```

second

```
Large conductance channel activation with decreases myogenic and neurogenic contractions of rat detrusor smooth muscle.
```